# How to create tag support list in asp.net

Tags: html, css

how to implement tags list in asp.net c# 
like Tags used stackoverflow

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried that we can help with? SO isn't a site where you simply post what you want and get working code back.

Comment: [**This**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) might help you!

Comment: As per the comment by @Zhihao, http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in multiple projects.[image: Chosen Screenshot]

> **Setup**
>
> Using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is easy as can be.
>
> - [Download](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases) the plugin and copy the chosen files to your app.
> - Activate
>     the plugin on the select boxes of your choice:
>
>   - `$(".chosen-select").chosen()`
> - [Disco](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UkSPUDpe0U8#t=11s).

Google can also be your friend:

http://coderbay.com/most-popular-jquery-multiselect-plugins/

> [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)
>   [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
>   [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)
>   [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)
>   [jQuery UIx Multiselect](http://mind2soft.com/labs/jquery/multiselect/)
>   [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi)
>   [FCBKComplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html)
>   [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
>   [Multiselect](http://loudev.com/)